# Mutualising multi-threaded calls to EJB from Servlet

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, servlets

I have a Servlet that makes an EJB call to a backing server which takes about a second to return some data that changes reasonably regularly.

I can't cache the data on the servlet-side, so I have decided to put the call to the EJB into a separate thread and use a Future to get the data as late as possible. There is no reason why an invocation of a servlet concurrent to an existing invocation can't use the data returned from the first request to the EJB.  For instance, if there is already a thread waiting for the data from the EJB, don't make another request; use the data from the first request.

```
public MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

  //this lock protects all access to currentRosterRequest
  private static final ReentrantReadWriteLock LOCK = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

  private RosterEJB rosterEJB=...;

  //the executor service that will process the roster request
  private static final ExecutorService ROSTER_FETCH_EXECUTOR_SERVICE = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(new ThreadFactory() {
    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
      return new Thread(r, "roster-fetch");
    }
  });

  //the roster request task - this never changes, it never needs parameters
  private static final Callable<ArrayList<String>> ROSTER_FETCH_TASK = new Callable<ArrayList<String>>() {

      @Override
      public ArrayList<String> call() throws Exception {
          try {
              return rosterEJB.getRoster();
          } finally {
              //one way or another the roster request has terminated
              LOCK.writeLock().lock();
              try {
                  //clear out the static variable
                  MyServlet.currentRosterRequest = null;
              } finally {
                  LOCK.writeLock().unlock();
              }
          }
      }
  };

  //the currently active request
  private static Future<ArrayList<String>> currentRosterRequest = null;

  public void doGet(...) {

    //obtain or create the current roster request
    final Future<ArrayList<String>> localRosterRequest = getLocalRosterRequest();

    //do other things

    //wait up to two seconds for data from the roster request
    final Boolean hasAccess = localRosterRequest.get(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS).contains(user.toLowerCase());

    //etc
  }

  private Future<ArrayList<String>> getLocalRosterRequest() {
    Future<ArrayList<String>> localRosterRequest;
    LOCK.readLock().lock();
    try {
        localRosterRequest = currentRosterRequest; //get a reference to the current request, if there is one
    } finally {
        LOCK.readLock().unlock();
    }
    if (localRosterRequest == null) { //if there wasn't a current request
        LOCK.writeLock().lock();
        try {
            if (currentRosterRequest == null) { //if there still isn't a current request, create a new one
                currentRosterRequest = ROSTER_FETCH_EXECUTOR_SERVICE.submit(ROSTER_FETCH_TASK);
            }
            localRosterRequest = currentRosterRequest; //get a reference to the current request
        } finally {
            LOCK.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }
    return localRosterRequest; //return the reference to the current request
  }
}
```

(I have left the majority of the servlet out - the main thing I want reviewing is the method `getLocalRosterRequest()`.)

**My aims:**

- If there is a request already underway, don't create a new request, use the existing one.
- If a new GET comes in when there is no request underway, create a new request, and make it available to subsequent callers.
- Avoid deadlocks!

**My questions:**

1. Is this threadsafe? I can't see a way that threads could block.
2. Does it put the servlet container at risk? I'm using Tomcat 6
3. Is there a better way?

Comment: I am not sure this compiles: `private RosterEJB rosterEJB=...;`

Comment: No, it won't - like I said I've left out a few bits and pieces to save a bit of space. It's mainly getLocalRosterRequest() that needs reviewing.

Comment: it's much easier to do a review if you can Copy&Paste the code into the IDE of your preference. I suggest you add something to make that compile, as we'll probably need it either way ;)

Comment: Voting to close because the code contains handwaving of various areas. This makes reviewing hard and leaves unanswered, dead questions. I understand you want the review to focus on those parts, but by making the context unavailable, overarching answers are impossible to provide.

Comment: Not sure how I missed this question 4 months ago... it's a nice question. Voting to leave open. It has enough context to review the method doing the concurrency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concurrency looks complete to me in the sense that I cannot see any places it can fail, or block significantly. The static `LOCK` and `Future` make sense. The `getLocalRosterRequest` itself is technically correct in the sense that it returns the right results, without logic problems. There is **no need** for the double-check locking though. It saves nothing, and solves nothing, other than creating two separate lock points.

Additionally, methods should not return concrete-types when interface-types would be available. Your method (and Future should be of type `List<String>` and not `ArrayList<String>`

Your code pulls the `writeLock()` from the `LOCK`, and locks on that. There are only two places where you use `LOCK` (one in the `call`, the other in the `get`). Neither of them need a sub-lock of the `LOCK`, they can both operate on the `LOCK` itself.

Your code would be simpler, and slightly faster, as simply:

```
  private Future<List<String>> getLocalRosterRequest() {
        LOCK.lock();
        try {
            if (currentRosterRequest == null) { //if there isn't a current request, create a new one
                currentRosterRequest = ROSTER_FETCH_EXECUTOR_SERVICE.submit(ROSTER_FETCH_TASK);
            }
            return currentRosterRequest; //return a reference to the current request
        } finally {
            LOCK.unlock();
        }
  }
```

and then, in the `call` method, you would have:

```
      try {
          return rosterEJB.getRoster();
      } finally {
          //one way or another the roster request has terminated
          LOCK.lock();
          try {
              //clear out the static variable
              MyServlet.currentRosterRequest = null;
          } finally {
              LOCK.unlock();
          }
      }
```